# Some excellent items may be permanently destroyed unless I act. What should I do?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

In Dungeon Crawl Stone Soup, I'm on a level with a vault. The vault contains stone-walled rooms that I still haven't found a way to enter. I've cleared the rest of the level though.

I heard one single solitary slurping sound. Then I walked around and searched for maybe 50 or 100 more turns. I haven't heard any more slurping sounds.

I fear that the vault contains really good generated items. Acquirement-class items. Plus, Crawl doesn't allow save scumming. So if the jelly eats the items, they'll be deleted from my savefile too. I'll never be able to get those items.

What should I do?

(Note: My character isn't a follower of Jiyva.)

Comment: On second thought, I plan to keep playing even without an answer. I realize that I'm playing Crawl to have fun, not to deal optimally with every single rare situation that comes up. If the items get destroyed because I didn't wait for an answer, then so be it. I'll still have fun.

Comment: That's the correct attitude.

Comment: [This wiki article talks about common vaults.](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Example_Vaults)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally, I would not worry about it.  By the time you find a way in, the Jelly will be done clearing the vault.  However, Jellies don't eat artifacts, so I would find a way in at some point, just to check for those.

Non-artifact items are common enough throughout the game that it is not likely that you will miss whatever is in the vault.